# Add auto suffix to column name R

Tags: r

This is probably pretty basic but I can't quite get to do it. What I'd like to do is add "auto" suffixes say from numbers 1-9 or letters A-G. How do I do this?
 Here's what I tried and what I'd like to do:

```
for(i in which(colnames(mydata)=="Expt_1")){
  names(mydata)<-paste("Expt",suffix=i)
}
```

Here's what I need to have
`Cell`   `Expt_1`   `Expt_2`   `Expt_3`   `Expt_4`         `and so on`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one option which generates the sequence to be used in the replacement.

```
suffix <- c(1:length(which(names(mydata)=="Expt_1")))
names(mydata)[which(colnames(mydata)=="Expt_1")] <- paste0("Expt_", suffix)
```

Answer (score 1):

You also can use `set_names()` from the `purrr` package to supply a function to add a suffix:

`purrr::set_names(head(mtcars), paste0("Expt_",1:ncol(mtcars)))`

Comment: That's simple and elegant!